# what does backslash do in this php code?

Tags: php, backslash

```
<?php 
   $cons = \CONSTANTE_NAME; 
   //or 
   $st = \get_magic_quotes_gpc();
?>
```

## I would like to know the effects of doing this or not.

Comment: This seems to be a namespace related thing. You can read more about namespaces here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5 has introduced namespaces. Read about them on [PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php).

The backslash indicates this function or constant name is in your root namespace.